# Need a Browser Based SSH Terminal Client -- WordPress Plugin?

Tags: web-apps, web-development, web-browser, ssh, shell-scripting

I have a network of about 150 users who need to reserve instruments daily using our custom Perl script on a Solaris signup computer that is accessed using an SSH client like Putty. This is a pain point for our users and I wish for them to be able to access the signup computer directly through our webpage without having to download Putty or a plugin for their browser. Is there a server side terminal SSH plugin that preferably can be installed through WordPress that will accomplish this task?

Ideally what I would like is to see the terminal open in a small window or tab of the browser. Prefer professionally maintained and supported softwares vs. free unsupported software.

Comment: There is a wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web-based_SSH) for ssh in the browser, but you would probably be better off writing a web front-end to convert standard html forms to ssh requests to your perl backend.

Comment: All users have a different SSH login/password I guess? Do you already have a Wordpress site with the same login/passwords that you need to integrate with, or is a solution from scratch OK?

Comment: Yes all users have their own accounts on the signup computer.  They are not the same as the WP logins which they wouldn't have anyway.  I just want a SECURE terminal to launch when our users click a link on our webpage preferably in a browser tab.

Comment: The Chrome built in one tends to work the fastest in my experience.

Comment: To update this question I wanted to tell you my solution.  I ended going with Shellinabox which IS installed serverside.  It does what I want with just a little bit of configuration.  You can find it on Github.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try https://github.com/billchurch/WebSSH2 It is not a WordPress plugin. It uses socket.io xterm.js and express so you will have to install some applications on the  server-side.

Another option is https://github.com/chjj/tty.js/ TTY.js, created using node.js and socket.io

Another option is this HTML5 terminal. It also uses no Browser plugins: https://github.com/liftoff/GateOne It is written in Python

Also if you would like to build your own ssh client, by communicating with your server you can use jQuery terminal: https://terminal.jcubic.pl/

Comment: Thanks -- I need time to research your suggestions but they look pretty good;)

Answer (score 2):

I found a little app called "Shell In A Box" that I installed on the server and it does everything I need.

[Shell In A Box Github](https://github.com/shellinabox/shellinabox)

Comment: This is no longer maintained?

Comment: @ThisIsNotMyRealName - It works is all I know.

Answer (score 1):

Bastillion is a web-based SSH console that centrally manages administrative access to systems. - https://www.bastillion.io